# Number of ways to reach N from 0 using only 2 or 3?

Tags: algorithm, fibonacci

I am solving this problem where we need to reach from X=0 to X=N.We can only take a step of 2 or 3 at a time.

For each step of 2 we have a probability of 0.2 and for each step of 3 we have a probability of 0.8.How can we find the total probability to reach N.

> e.g. for reaching 5,
>
> ```
> 2+3 with probability =0.2 * 0.8=0.16
>
> 3+2 with probability =0.8 * 0.2=0.16 total = 0.32.
> ```

**My initial thoughts:**

Number of ways can be found out by simple Fibonacci sequence. 
f(n)=f(n-3)+f(n-2);
But how do we remember the numbers so that we can multiply them to find the probability?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be solved using `Dynamic programming`.

Lets call the function `F(N)` = probability to reach `0` using only 2 and 3 when `the starting number is N`

```
F(N) = 0.2*F(N-2) + 0.3*F(N-3)
```

Base case:

```
F(0) = 1 and F(k)= 0 where k< 0
```

So the DP code would be somthing like that:

```
F[0] = 1;
for(int i = 1;i<=N;i++){
     if(i>=3)
         F[i] = 0.2*F[i-2] + 0.8*F[i-3];
     else if(i>=2)
         F[i] = 0.2*F[i-2];
     else
         F[i] = 0;
}
return F[N];
```

This algorithm would run in `O(N)`

Answer (score 2):

Some clarifications about this solution: I assume the only allowed operation for generating the number from 2s and 3s is addition (your definition would allow substraction aswell) and the input-numbers are always valid (2 <= input). Definition: a unique row of numbers means: no other row with the same number of 3s and 2s in another order is in scope.

We can reduce the problem into multiple smaller problems:

**Problem A: finding all sequences of numbers that can sum up to the given number. (Unique rows of numbers only)**
Start by finding the minimum-number of 3s required to build the given number, which is simply `input % 2`. The maximum-number of 3s that can be used to build the input can be calculated this way:

```
int max_3 = (int) (input / 3);
if(input - max_3 == 1)
    --max_3;
```

Now all sequences of numbers that sum up to `input` must hold between `input % 2` and `max_3` 3s. The 2s can be easily calculated from a given number of 3s.

**Problem B: calculating the probability for a given list and it's permutations to be the result**
For each unique row of numbers, we can easily derive all permutations. Since these consist of the same number, they have the same likeliness to appear and produce the same sum. The likeliness can be calculated easily from the row: `0.8 ^ number_of_3s * 0.2 ^ number_of_2s`. Next step would be to calculate the number of different permuatations. Calculating all distinct sets with a specific number of 2s and 3s can be done this way: Calculate all possible distributions of 2s in the set: `(number_of_2s + number_of_3s)! / (number_of_3s! * numer_of_2s!)`. Basically just the number of possible distinct permutations.

**Now from theory to praxis**
Since the math is given, the rest is pretty straight forward:

```
define prob:
    input: int num
    output: double

    double result = 0.0

    int min_3s = (num % 2)
    int max_3s = (int) (num / 3)
    if(num - max_3 == 1)
        --max_3

    for int c3s in [min_3s , max_3s]
        int c2s = (num - (c3s * 3)) / 2

        double p = 0.8 ^ c3s * 0.2 * c2s
        p *= (c3s + c2s)! / (c3s! * c2s!)

        result += p

    return result
```

Comment: @Cyclotron3x3 it's quite out of the box, yes, but still more efficient than your idea, if implemented properly.

Comment: indeed... mine was just an initial thoughts with no efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of jumping into the programming, you can use math.

Let p(n) be the probability that you reach the location that is n steps away.

Base cases:

```
p(0)=1
p(1)=0
p(2)=0.2
```

[Linear recurrence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients)

```
p(n+3)=0.2 p(n+1) + 0.8 p(n)
```

You can solve this in closed form by finding the exponential solutions to the linear recurrent relation.

c^3 = 0.2 c + 0.8

c = 1, (-5 +- sqrt(55)i)/10

Although this was cubic, c=1 will always be a solution in this type of problem since there is a constant nonzero solution.

Because the roots are distinct, all solutions are of the form a1(1)^n + a2((-5+sqrt(55)i) / 10)^n + a3((-5-sqrt(55)i)/10)^n. You can solve for a1, a2, and a3 using the initial conditions:

```
a1=5/14 
a2=(99-sqrt(55)i)/308
a3=(99+sqrt(55)i)/308
```

This gives you a nonrecursive formula for p(n):

```
p(n)=5/14+(99-sqrt(55)i)/308((-5+sqrt(55)i)/10)^n+(99+sqrt(55)i)/308((-5-sqrt(55)i)/10)^n
```

One nice property of the non-recursive formula is that you can read off the asymptotic value of 5/14, but that's also clear because the average value of a jump is 2(1/5)+ 3(4/5) = 14/5, and you almost surely hit a set with density 1/(14/5) of the integers. You can use the magnitudes of the other roots, 2/sqrt(5)~0.894, to see how rapidly the probabilities approach the asymptotics.

```
5/14 - (|a2|+|a3|) 0.894^n < p(n) < 5/14 + (|a2|+|a3|) 0.894^n
|5/14 - p(n)| < (|a2|+|a3|) 0.894^n
```

Comment: So if you use double precision, then p (n) = 5/14 for n >= 400.

Comment: @gnasher729: Yes. You can use this as a test of how much roundoff error you get from the programming methods: Compute p(400) using dynamic programming and see how far this differs from 5/14.

Comment: I was not aware about Linear recurrence relation. I knew someway around their must be a DP solution...thanks..

Answer (score 1):

f(n, p) = f(n-3, p*.8) + f(n -2, p*.2)

Start p at 1.

If n=0 return p, if n <0 return 0.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the (terribly inefficient) recursive algorithm, start from the start and calculate in how many ways you can reach subsequent steps, i.e. using ['dynamic programming'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Fibonacci_sequence). This way, you can easily calculate the probabilities and also have a complexity of only *O(n)* to calculate everything up to step *n*.

For each step, memorize the possible ways of reaching that step, if any (no matter how), and the probability of reaching that step. For the zeroth step (the start) this is `(1, 1.0)`.

```py
steps = [(1, 1.0)]
```

Now, for each consecutive step `n`, get the previously computed possible ways `poss` and probability `prob` to reach steps *n-2* and *n-3* (or `(0, 0.0)` in case of `n < 2` or `n < 3` respectively), add those to the combined possibilities and probability to reach that new step, and add them to the list.

```py
for n in range(1, 10):
    poss2, prob2 = steps[n-2] if n >= 2 else (0, 0.0)
    poss3, prob3 = steps[n-3] if n >= 3 else (0, 0.0)
    steps.append( (poss2 + poss3, prob2 * 0.2 + prob3 * 0.8) )
```

Now you can just get the numbers from that list:

```py
>>> for n, (poss, prob) in enumerate(steps):
...     print "%s\t%s\t%s" % (n, poss, prob)
0   1   1.0
1   0   0.0
2   1   0.2
3   1   0.8
4   1   0.04
5   2   0.32        <-- 2 ways to get to 5 with combined prob. of 0.32
6   2   0.648
7   3   0.096
8   4   0.3856
9   5   0.5376
```

(Code is in Python)

Note that this will get you *both* the number of possible ways of reaching a certain step (e.g. "first 2, then 3" or "first 3, then 2" for 5), *and* the probability to reach that step in one go. Of course, if you need *only* the probability, you can just use single numbers instead of tuples.

Comment: can you provide an example how your code is working for N=5 to get 0.32. I am not a python coder.:)

Comment: @Cyclotron3x3 The `n=5` case is highlighted in the output. To calculate the list up to `n`, you have to use `for i in range(1, n + 1):`, because the to-parameter in `range` in Python is exclusive. And of course, the algorithm should be easily transferrable to other languages, I just prefer Python over pseudo-code so I can test it.

Comment: step2, p2 = steps[i-2] if i >= 2 else (0, 0.0).. what is the meaning of this line specially that last else (0,0.0)

Comment: @Cyclotron3x3 That means: If in step 2 or later, get the values from step n-2, otherwise use (0, 0.0), i.e. zero possible ways to reach that step and zero probability. It's another way to do what @yahya does with that `if / else if / else` block.